# Play COD4 multiplayer behind proxy

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy, gaming

At our college we have a good wifi connectivity. I might sound silly but I would like to play call of duty 4 online using the wifi network. But since there is no way to configure proxy in cod I am unable to do that.
I have seen people suggesting to use proxifier. But I am not sure how to use it.
If someone knows a solution please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you read up on it first?

Answer (score 1):

They probably use a proxy because it's the only way to connect out of the network. All other connections are blocked, so that people won't use the internet connection to play Call of Duty.

The proxy is for HTTP connections. Call of Duty probably doesn't use HTTP for their networking, so you can't use it to play.